# Автоудаление записей MySQL через заданное время (redbeamPHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите как сделать автоудаление записей MySQL через заданное время (redbeamPHP). Пример запросом MySQL есть

```
$del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `time` < now() - interval 30 second");
```

только как это сделать в RedBeamPHP?

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$posts = R::load('posts', $id);
R::trash($posts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вставляйте куда нужно, метод R::exec(); попросту делает запрос в базу данных

```
R::exec("DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `active` = 1 AND `time` < now() - interval 30 second");
```

[Вот документация по querying](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/querying)  в RedBeanPHP

Comment: подскажите еще, а как это сделать чтобы запись удалялась если в столбце active значение 1, а не удалялось — 2 и 3?

Comment: и где это вставлять, где добавление записи, или где вывод?

Comment: о каком добавлении записи вы говорите? я что-то не пойму